# Reuseable help Button and help popup

Tags: wpf, button, popup, controltemplate

I have about 30 views and corresponding VMs in my application. I have a `HelpButton` next to most user controls which gives some description of what the field is for. When the user clicks on that `Button`, a `Popup` opens and gives the description. What will be the best way to make this functionality reusable in all the views?

I have created a `ControlTemplate` for the `HelpButton` and the help `Popup` but can I go further than this? Thanks.

```
<Style x:Key="HelpButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}" >
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Ellipse Focusable="True" Height="16" Width="16">
                    <Ellipse.Fill>
                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="../../Resources/Icons/Help.png" />
                    </Ellipse.Fill>
                </Ellipse>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

I see that it's been a while since this question was asked, but I figured I would reply in case someone else comes across this problem and is looking for a solution.

Put it in a ResourceDictionary in a separate Resources.xaml that is accessible from all of your other views:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns...>
    <Style x:Key="HelpButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}" >
        ...
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Then use it from your Resources section (as you no doubt did before) in your xaml like this:

```
<UserControl xmlns...>
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources.xaml"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Button Style="{StaticResource HelpButton}" />
</UserControl>
```